# Retrieve every model and return three values

Tags: html, model, yii2, html-table

I am looking for a way to retrieve all models in a database. Then loop through all of the models and read out the values for `name`, `firstname` and `phonenumber`.

So far I've gotten this and failed to go past it:

```
$searchModel = new EmployeeSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

I am then looking to implement those three values in a simple HTML table:

```
<tr><td>$firstname</td><td>$name</td><td>$phone</td></tr>
```

The table should be part of a PDF output, so ideally I would save it to a variable:

```
$html_table = '<tr><td>$firstname</td><td>$name</td><td>$phone</td></tr>';
```

I would need to get this for every model that fulfills the criteria of `status = 'active'` in the database.

So far I've only been able to get tables via `gridView` and not in a HTML template either.

Comment: What's the exact problem now?

Comment: Getting the models and looping through them.

Comment: You already have some good answers, but I suggest you use `Html` helper to properly encode text within tags. Something along the lines of `Html::tag('td', $firstname)`. This will ensure everything is properly encoded (if, for example, `$firstname` contains `>` or `<`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need a data provider to achieve this, you could simply try :

```
$models = Employee::find()->where(['status'=>'active'])->orderBy('name ASC')->all();
foreach ($models as $model) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$model->firstname}</td><td>{$model->name}</td><td>{$model->phone}</td></tr>";
}
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#querying-data

Comment: How can I add an Order By clause? Your solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all models like this:

```
$employees = Employee::find()
    ->select('firstname, name, phone')
    ->asArray()
    ->where(['status'=>'active'])
    ->all();
```

This way you will get an array of arrays containing the 3 selected fields, so now you only need to use a foreach to loop through them and create the table:

```
$html = '<table>';
foreach($employees as $employee) {
    $html .= '<tr><td>'.$employee['firstname'].'</td><td>'.$employee['name'].'</td><td>'.$employee['phone'].'</td></tr>';
}
$html .= '</table>'
```